# More info inside expandable recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

i hope that you could help me.
i want to use a expandablerecyclerview but i dont need to expand a list of other elements like the lib says

library example

[image]
I just need that the item expand and show more info of the item inside the recycler

Answer (score 0):

You can use [advanced recyclerview's](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) expandable future

```
public class ExpandableWithHeaderFooterExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_minimal);

        OnListItemClickMessageListener clickListener = new OnListItemClickMessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(String message) {
                View container = findViewById(R.id.container);
                Snackbar.make(container, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        // Setup expandable feature and RecyclerView
        RecyclerViewExpandableItemManager expMgr = new RecyclerViewExpandableItemManager(null);

        // Create wrapped adapter:  MyItemAdapter -> expMgr.createWrappedAdapter -> MyHeaderFooterAdapter
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        adapter = new SimpleDemoExpandableItemAdapter(expMgr, clickListener);
        adapter = expMgr.createWrappedAdapter(adapter);
        adapter = new DemoHeaderFooterAdapter(adapter, clickListener);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // NOTE: need to disable change animations to ripple effect work properly
        ((SimpleItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

        expMgr.attachRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}
```